# Speech portal does not show the list of logs

Tags: azure-cognitive-services, speech

I've created a custom speech model and deployed it. When I select the endpoint I can export the logs at the bottom of the page. Logging is enabled for this endpoint and it worked until 2 weeks ago. Now, when i click the "Export log" button, the spinner appears for a second or two but it does not show the list of logs. I took a look on the HTTP answer, which contained json data, telling me that there should be a lot of logs ready for download.

So my assumption is that this might be an error of the page? I've tried it using latest Firefox and Chrome browser. Edge does not work either. Deleting cookies and cache data does not work either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a bug in the current UI of Speech Studio Portal, and thanks for reporting this, we will fix in our next release, which will come in this week.

Comment: It's fixed. Thanks